# How do I make my native Windows 8 Lenovo laptop boot grub?

Tags: installation, grub2, bootloader

I like to think I'm not a novice on this issue but this situation is proving me wrong. I've been trying for about two days to figure out a way for my Lenovo S415 to install Ubuntu. I have disabled SecureBoot, turned on Legacy support, and I have gotten it to the point of having the USB appear in the list of boot options. But when I do try, it says missing operating system and kicks back over to the main Windows boot controller.

I cannot even get grub to appear at all. I don't think it's a problem with the flash drive; I've tried every USB creator more than once and it solves nothing. The BIOS settings are changed to everything that seems reasonable. I want to completely wipe the drive and replace it with Ubuntu. I don't care about keeping Windows on here.

If all else fails, I have another computer here to use and I don't care if I have to wipe this one in the process. How would I install Ubuntu from scratch?

It's been a long two days and I greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lenovo S415 with the AMD A6 processor. I was able to boot into a live USB install of Ubuntu (and Mint as well). Here's what I did...

1. In BIOS Boot window,

   - Boot Mode: Legacy Support
   - Boot Priority: Legacy First
   - USB Boot: Enabled
2. After setting the above in the BIOS Boot window, I powered off the laptop, plugged in the USB containing Ubuntu, and then pressed the Novo button (on the side of the S415 laptop near the regular power button).
3. Laptop powers on, shows me a "Novo Button Menu" with 4 options, one of which is "Boot Menu". I choose that and press Enter.
4. A new "Boot Manager" screen opens up and I see

   - SATA HDD
   - Generic USB Flash Disk
   - Network Boot: Realtek PXE
   - Windows Boot Manager
   - EFI USB Device (Generic USB Flash Disk)

I choose the last one (EFI USB device) and press Enter. I see a brief message "Secure Boot not enabled" and in less than a second, I see the GRUB menu for Ubuntu with options "Try Ubuntu without installing", "Install Ubuntu" etc.

Hope this helps! Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

just in case any one else finds this like I did, here's what I did.

Put the ISO on a thumb drive.  interrupt the boot, tell it to boot to USB (this was a pain, i just kept not getting it to work, until the windows 8 menu came up to "reboot to startup menu" or some such choice)

boot.  install.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this a bit to explain how you interrupted the boot.